# Foreach loop async-await

Tags: c#, foreach, async-await

I have a question about good practice with async-await in foreach loop.

My method looks like this

```
 public async Task<List<Category>> GetCategoriesAsync(string partOfName,
        CancellationToken ct = default(CancellationToken))
    {
        string lowerCasePartOfName = partOfName.ToLower();

        var categories = await _context.ECATEGORIES
            .Where(a => a.NAME.ToLower().Contains(lowerCasePartOfName))
            .ProjectTo<Category>()
            .ToListAsync(ct);

        //version1 #Beginning 
        var i = 0;
        foreach (var parentId in categories)
        {
            var categoryParent = await _context.ECATEGORIES
                .Where(a => a.ID == parentId.ParentId)
                .Select(s => s.NAME)
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(ct);

            categories[i].CategoryParent = categoryParent;
            i++;
        }
        //version1 #End

        //version2 #Beginning 
        categories.ForEach(async x => x.CategoryParent = await _context.ECATEGORIES
            .Where(a => a.ID == x.ParentId)
            .Select(s => s.NAME).FirstOrDefaultAsync(ct));
        //version2 #End

        return categories;
    }
```

Version1 and version2 gives same result but I would like to ask which is better practice for async tasks or maybe none of them.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Both are bad in that the code could be rewritten to make use of a proper join. That would make 1 db call instead of 1 call per category + 1 (for the initial call). But strictly answering your question, it does not matter: pick the one you feel most comfortable with.

Comment: Problem I had is that, parentId is often duplicated and I couldn't use .Contains

Answer (score 1):

Both are bad in that the code could be rewritten to make use of a proper join. That would make 1 db call instead of 1 call per category + 1 (for the initial call). But strictly answering your question, it does not matter: pick the one you feel most comfortable with

> Problem I had is that, parentId is often duplicated and I couldn't use .Contains

You can use a left join to do the same thing but all in 1 DB call which is cheaper than 1 call per result.

```
string lowerCasePartOfName = partOfName.ToLower();

var categories = await (from category in _context.ECATEGORIES.Where(a => a.NAME.ToLower().Contains(lowerCasePartOfName))
    from parent in _context.ECATEGORIES.Where(parent => parent.ID == category.ParentId).DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new Category
    {
        Id = category.ID,
        CategoryParent = parent.NAME,
    }).ToListAsync();
```

If your schema is setup to be case insensitive then you can omit the `ToLower` calls as well. You can check this by looking at the COLLATION.

```
.Where(a => a.NAME.Contains(lowerCasePartOfName))
```

Comment: Sorry but I don't know how to use it in my method:/
In your code parent is IEnumarable<ECATEGORY> so I can't reference like parent.NAME .

Comment: in braces {} property parent still stays as a collection.

Comment: @janek9971 - give me 1 second, I will fix it.

Comment: var categories = await _context.ECATEGORIES
                .Where(a => a.NAME.ToLower().Contains(lowerCasePartOfName))
                .GroupJoin(_context.ECATEGORIES, child => child.PARENTID, parent => parent.ID, (category, parent) => new { Category = category, ParentName = parent.FirstOrDefault()})
                .Select(s => new Category
                {
                    Id = s.Category.ID,
                    CategoryParent = s.ParentName.NAME,
                    ParentId = s.Category.PARENTID,
          
                })
                .ToListAsync(ct);

Comment: I think now is ok? If yes I post as my answer to my question.

I changed parent.Name to parent.FirstOrDefault() and then retrieve Name

Comment: @janek9971 - that works but I rewrote it using linq instead of lambda which is easier to read (IMO). Either one will work.

Comment: @janek9971 - if you are curious how that works see https://stackoverflow.com/a/23558389/1260204

Comment: @janek9971 - glad to help. Please consider marking an answer if this solves your problem (answers your question).

Comment: I have a last question is it possible to still use automapper ProjectTo<> in this case?

Comment: @janek9971 - I am not sure, I am not familiar with AutoMapper

Comment: Upon reflection, I think that is not possible without adding ForMember in CreateMap  cause CategoryParent is not get in a straight way which would be more unreadable.